# Which Entity Framework SQL Server CE DLL should I be using?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I developed an application using Entity Framework 4.1 and SQL Server CE 4.0.  The application uses a private deployment of SQL CE to simplify installation...

Recently I upgraded from EF 4.1 to 4.3.  I'm still in the process of coding the migration of the database(s) from EF 4.1 to 4.3.  It does seem to work with new databases though.

My question concerns the NuGet package called [EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact).  Does this package replace one of the libraries in the SQL Server CE 4.0 private installation?  I'm having difficulty finding straightforward explanations to what classes this package provides and what it potentially replaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is the same DLL that is supplied with SQL Server Compact itself, but a SP1 prerelease. Avoid using it for now, until 4.0 SP1 is RTM, just use the one you have used until now (System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll)

Comment: Thanks.  So do you have any idea if MS is going to switch to deployment of SQL Compact using NuGet; similar to what they've done with EF?  I like NuGet and will switch to using it if they plan to release RTM and SP's in addition to or instead of downloaded MSI's.

Comment: SQLCompact is already available via NuGet, but it its not the Private Deployment DLL that is included (4.0.0.1) due to Medium Trust requirements for ASP.NET